# ¿Cómo hacer un bucle que lea valores y los compare para guardar secuencias crecientes?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Tengo que hacer un programa que lea valores y diga cuál es la secuencia ascendente mayor de temperaturas, en qué posición empieza y cuál es su longitud, pero no sé bien cómo hacerlo.

El programa termina si se introduce el número -1 y es ahí cuando debe imprimir en pantalla el resultado. Sólo puedo usar comandos básicos como `while`, `if` `else` o hasta `for` pero no mucho más.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Spanish");
    double temperatura1, temperatura2;
    int contador1, contador2, posicion, contador3;

    temperatura2=0;
    contador2=0;
    contador1=0;
    contador3=0;

    while(temperatura1!=-1 && temperatura2!=-1){

        if(temperatura1!=-1 && temperatura2!=-1){
            cout << "Introduzca la temperatura: ";
            cin >> temperatura1;
        }

        if(temperatura1!=-1 && temperatura2!=-1){
            if(temperatura2>temperatura1){
                if(contador2>contador1)
                    contador1=contador2;
                contador2=1;
            }
        }   
        if(temperatura1!=-1 && temperatura2!=-1){
            contador3++;
            contador2++;
        }

        if(temperatura1!=-1 && temperatura2!=-1){
            cout << "Introduzca la temperatura: ";
            cin >> temperatura2;

        }
        if(temperatura1!=-1 && temperatura2!=-1){
            if(temperatura1>temperatura2){
                if(contador2>contador1)
                    contador1=contador2;
                contador2=1;
            }
        }
            if(temperatura1!=-1 && temperatura2!=-1){
            contador3++;
            contador2++;
            }
    }

    posicion=contador3-contador1-contador2+1;
    if(contador2>contador1){
        contador1=contador2;
        posicion=contador3-contador1+1;
    }
    cout << "\n" << posicion << "\n";
    cout << contador1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es importante mencionar que con `float`s y `double`s es imposible utilizar los operadores `==` o `!=`, porque al guardar, por ejemplo, un `1` en una variable de dicho tipo, en memoria, dicho `1` podría realmente guardarse como `1.00000001` o como `0.99999999999999999999` y similares. Lo mismo es aplicable a `-1` o cualquier otro número de punto flotante, siempre hay problemas de precisión.

Como consejo adicional, utiliza nombres descriptivos (y no tantos `contador`es que uno no sabe para qué sirve cada uno hasta que se estudia el código). Y como `longest_init` es más corto que `inicio_mas_larga`, pues el código va en inglés (te lo digo desde ya, en inglés se escribe menos):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> // para std::abs (que no es lo mismo que `abs`).

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int longest_init = 0, longest_end = 0;
    int curr_init = 0, curr_end = 0;

    double curr_temp, former_temp;

    cin >> former_temp;

    // Si la temperatura anterior es diferente a -1
    // (es decir, si no está pegado a `-1`).
    while (std::abs(former_temp - -1.) >= 0.0001) {

       ++curr_end;

       cin >> curr_temp;

       // Comprobar fin de secuencia, bien por -1, bien por no ascendiente
       // Comprobar si secuencia actual es mayor que la secuencia anterior
       if (std::abs(curr_temp - -1) < .0001 or curr_temp <= former_temp) {

           if ((curr_end - curr_init) > (longest_end - longest_init)) {
              longest_init = curr_init;
              longest_end = curr_end;
           }

           curr_init = curr_end;
       }

       former_temp = curr_temp;
    }

    cout << "Secuencia (inicio, longitud): (" << longest_init
         << ", " << (longest_end - longest_init) << ")" << endl;
}
```

[Ejecuta](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/884271803029e36f) este código.

**Varias notas**:

- Respecto al `abs`, hay que tener en cuenta que `abs` es una función que proviene de C, y por retrocompatibilidad (C++ intenta ser lo más retrocompatible con C que pueda, de modo que la mayoría de los programas de C puedan compilarse con un compilador de C++), C++ tiene, para cada función de C, varias funciones con el mismo nombre. En el caso de `abs`, hay dos versiones:

  - La simple función `abs`, que solo funciona con enteros `abs(int)`, y que no está dentro del `namespace std` (porque C no tiene espacios de nombres).
  - La función `std::abs`, con diferentes sobrecargas para `int`, `float`s, etc (en C, las otras sobrecargas están disponibles a través de las funciones `fabs`, `labs`, etc).

  Por ese motivo, aunque ya haya incluído `using namespace std;` al inicio del código, vuelvo a especificar `std::abs` para evitar que se elija la versión de C (que tiene preferencia), y que solo funciona con enteros.
- En caso de que haya varias secuencias máximas (del mismo tamaño), el algoritmo se queda con la primera de ellas.
- La comparación que utilizo para ver si la secuencia es decreciente (`curr_temp <= former_temp`), podrá chocarte el hecho de que haya utilizado una comparación de igualdad (`<=`) cuando justo antes acabo de decir que no te puedes fiar por problemas de precisión, y es cierto. Lo he dejado así por simplicidad al no estar comparando con otra constante, sino con un elemento anterior de la secuencia (que sufre los mismos problemas de precisión), así que asumimos que el usuario no va a introducir manualmente nunca valores tan parecidos entre sí. En el caso del `-1` la comparación era obligatoria porque el usuario, de hecho, puede introducir un `-1` que la aplicación luego recibe como un `-0.99999`. Si quieres hacer la comparación **un poco** más fiable, puedes hacer algo como:

  ```
  (curr_temp - .0001) <= former_temp
  ```

  así, de alguna manera, forzamos a que, si la temperatura actual es prácticamente igual a la anterior, al restarle un valor pequeño, forzamos a que sea menor a `former_temp` (lo de  mantener o no el `=` hasta cierto punto es opcional tras la resta). Pero insisto, si el usuario mete valores "normales" para un ejercicio de universidad, no vas a tener problemas, excepto con el `-1`, que la comparación mediante resta absoluta si es obligatoria.